# Массив, в котором лежит объект - PHP

Tags: php

Есть переменная, в которой такое содержимое:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 449 ) )
```

Как мне в PHP вывести 449 с помощью echo?

Comment: при составлении запроса вида "SELECT COUNT(*)..." можно было написать так:
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А обычный способ уже не в моде? :)

```
echo $array[0]->{"COUNT(*)"};
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
echo $array[0]['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не выводит ;-(